# How to get column name form a ListView using Linq(Type cast)

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, listview

i've a `ListView` control with many columns. I need to fill a `List<String>` with the column names.

By using a `for` loop we can do this like

```
for(int i=0;i<listView.Columns.Count;i++)
   {
     MyList.Add(listView.Columns[i].Text);
   }
```

but how to do this using LINQ?

instead of column , if we need the Text of `listViewItem` then we can do like

```
MyList=listView.itemo
               .OfType<ListViewItem>()
               .Select(X => X.Text.Trim())
               .ToList();
```

How to do this for Columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that for columns in the exact same way:

```
var yourList = listView.Columns
               .OfType<ColumnHeader>()
               .Select(header => header.Text.Trim())
               .ToList();
```